# Why does my Eclipse take so long to start up?

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Helios 64bit with 64bit java on a 64 bit windows 7 machine.  When I launch eclipse, it can take as long as 30 minutes before it comes to the workspace prompt. Once it hits the workspace prompt, everything is fine and works at normal speed.  Sometimes it will start and get to the prompt in as few as 30 seconds.  The startup speeds vary regardless of what else is running or not running on my computer.

I have 4 gb of ram, and my ini file is as below.  I've tried changing all of the values, and variations from [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse#144349).  the -clean or -refresh options all apply to after the selection of workspace, so don't help, same with deleting metadata.  On times when it takes the longest, Eclipse will open with only 20 mb of ram, and gain only about 16 kb a second.  While running with projects loaded, it usually uses 940 mb of ram.  The workspace prompt comes up right around 256 mb - the launcher perm size.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
C:/Java/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJava
Version=1.5
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms728m
-Xmx728m
```

If any has any ideas or has experienced this as well, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This is with it installed onto a fast, local disk that's free of errors?

Comment: Yes, it was the internal drive on the laptop and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that it is an issue with validators.  The Eclipse validators for JSP and HTML content can take an inordinate amount of time.  If you have a lot of these files, then validation can take "for ever".

The workaround is to open the Eclipse and/or Project preferences and disable the running of validators on startup, etc.

Comment: Tried disabling them, but didn't change the start up unfortunately.

Comment: If it's taking that long just to prompt for a workspace location, something is very, very wrong, and it's long before the validators even come into play.